# Heroku SSL EndPoint -- update cert gives Internal server error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku

I have a COMODO wildcard SSL certificate that I am trying to replace my old SSL certificate with.

I followed the guides here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint
http://ryan.mcgeary.org/2011/09/16/how-to-add-a-dnsimple-ssl-certificate-to-heroku/

Based off of these, I combined them in to one .pem:

```
cat STAR_[domain]_com.crt /
    EssentialSSLCA_2.crt /
    ComodoUTNSGCCA.crt /
    UTNAddTrustSGCCA.crt /
    AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt >> STAR_[domain]_com-bundle.pem
```

I then ran:

```
heroku certs:update STAR_[domain]_com-bundle.pem server.key
```

and I receive:

```
Updating SSL Endpoint hyogo-2759.herokussl.com for [heroku-app]... failed
 !    Internal server error.
 !    Run `heroku status` to check for known platform issues.
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: You might want to hit up Heroku support to see if they can help.

Comment: Looks like the answer was not using a .pem file and having as a .crt file. That wasn't from Heroku though -- this was from me pounding on my keyboard for hours.

Comment: Great, glad you figured it out. It'd be great if you could answer your own question so that others can find the answer quickly.

Comment: Yeah, I was freaking out a bit (deadline). Thanks for responding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the skinny is that Heroku's error messages were not very good and/or were not expecting what I gave them, hence the Internal Server Error lacking any specifics.

Heroku got back to me and said they will look in to better error messages for this, but I doubt that will happen.

```
The solution:
Instead of using the .pem extension, use .crt
```