# heroku ssl endpoint add cert give internal error, update gives undefined first for nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, endpoint

My SSL certificate expired, so I followed the directions to create an csr, activate my renewed cert, and cat the key and certs together.  From comodo through namecheap.  An update now says:

> $ heroku certs:update reserver.pem reserver.key
>   c:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/command/certs.rb:110:in `current_endpoint': undef
>   ined method`first' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
>          from c:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/command/certs.rb:79:in `update'
>          from c:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:148:in`run'
>          from c:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:9:in `start'
>          from c:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/heroku:28:in`'

and add now says the same as this other question
[Heroku SSL EndPoint -- update cert gives Internal server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14945971/heroku-ssl-endpoint-update-cert-gives-internal-server-error)
:

> $ heroku certs:add reserver.pem reserver.key
>   Adding SSL endpoint to

Most other heroku certs commands also have issues with undefined methods for nil.

I've repeated the process multiple times, and I believe my certs are okay.  Additional ideas to troubleshoot or fix would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was starting over again on a new computer AND downloading and installing the latest heroku toolbox (and updating the path manually to use the new heroku command).  I suspect that doing the same on the old computer would have fixed the issue, as well.